# apply a function over each row to find unique values in multiple columns

Tags: pandas

My data frame looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[0,1,2,3,4],
                   'date1': ['2020-12-01','2020-12-01',np.nan,'2018-12-01',np.nan],
                   'date2': ['2015-04-01','2015-04-01','2018-12-01','2018-12-01',np.nan],
                   'date3': [np.nan,'2013-12-01','2018-12-01','2018-12-01',np.nan]
})
```

I'm trying to apply a function like `nunique()` over each of the data columns for each ID to obtain then sum of distinct dates. I have tried using `agg()` function in groupby.

Resulted data frame would look like:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply [`Dateframe.nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) to selected *date* values:

```
df['uniq_sum'] = df.filter(like='date').nunique(axis=1)
```

---

```
   ID       date1       date2       date3  uniq_sum
0   0  2020-12-01  2015-04-01         NaN         2
1   1  2020-12-01  2015-04-01  2013-12-01         3
2   2         NaN  2018-12-01  2018-12-01         1
3   3  2018-12-01  2018-12-01  2018-12-01         1
4   4         NaN         NaN         NaN         0
```

Comment: Can I use this approach to lookup from list of columns? Something like...
`cols_to_include = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('date')]`
`df['uniq_sum'] = df[[cols_to_include]].apply(pd.Series.nunique, axis=1)`

Comment: @Ayan, you can simply filter by pattern `df.filter(like='date').apply(pd.Series.nunique, axis=1)`

Comment: @Ayan, sorry,  it's even simpler, I've missed that df itself has `nunique` functin, see my update

Comment: Thanks, I think you may want to keep your previous answer because of its 'uniqueness' :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) on `axis=1` after filtering out the ID column:

```
out = df[['ID']]
out['unique_sum'] = df.drop(columns='ID').nunique(axis=1)
```

Or with [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
out = df[['ID']]
out['unique_sum'] = df.filter(like='date').nunique(axis=1)
```

Or, as chained commands:

```
out = (
 df[['ID']]
 .assign(unique_sum=(df.drop(columns='ID').nunique(axis=1)))
 )
```

Output:

```
   ID  unique_sum
0   0           2
1   1           3
2   2           1
3   3           1
4   4           0
```